# SOLVED: Check Point firewall log format through syslog

Tags: firewall, syslog, checkpoint

I receive logs from a series of Check Point firewalls that I don't manage and they are very thorough, containing every possible information about the communication. They're also formatted like `field:"value";` making it very easy to parse.

An example:

```
Nov  5 10:23:15 CP-MGT-01 [action:"Accept"; flags:"417028"; ifdir:"inbound"; ifname:"bond1.112"; logid:"0"; loguid:"{0x********,0x********,0x********,0x********}"; origin:"10.3.1.125"; originsicname:"CN=CP_FW_Jupiter_01,O=CP-Manager..********"; sequencenum:"222"; time:"1636107795"; version:"5"; __policy_id_tag:"product=VPN-1 & FireWall-1[db_tag={********-********-********-********-********};mgmt=CP_MGT_01;date=1636104479;policy_name=FW_Jupiter_Startup_12_03_2015\]"; dst:"135.57.11.2"; inzone:"Internal"; layer_name:"FW_Jupiter_Startup_12_03_2015 Security"; layer_uuid:"********-********-********-********-********"; match_id:"654"; parent_rule:"0"; rule_action:"Accept"; rule_uid:"********-********-********-********-********"; outzone:"Internal"; product:"VPN-1 & FireWall-1"; proto:"6"; s_port:"65441"; service:"443"; service_id:"https"; src:"10.12.3.30"; src_machine_name:"********@********group.dom"; src_user_dn:"CN=John Doe - ********,OU=Office365,OU=********,OU=********,DC=********,DC=********,DC=dom "; src_user_name:"John Doe (********) "; user:"John Doe (********) "]
```

There's another network however that I'm in charge of and I don't know how to get the same output from the Check Point firewalls. The fields are space separated which makes it harder to parse and I get nowhere near the information that I get from the other properly configured system. Here's an example:

```
Nov  5 12:09:01 10.12.8.220 [Fields@1.3.6.1.4.1.2620 Log delay="1636110541" service_id="https" src="10.12.16.30" dst="10.12.8.14" proto="6" UP_match_table="TABLE_START" ROW_START="0" match_id="42" layer_uuid="*****-*****-*****-*****-*****" layer_name="Network" rule_uid="*****-*****-*****-*****-*****" rule_name="-> My_Rule" ROW_END="0" UP_match_table="TABLE_END" ProductName="VPN-1 & FireWall-1" svc="443" sport_svc="6606" ProductFamily="Network" #012]
```

Here are the specs of the network:
There are two sites, A and B, each of which has two firewalls

- CheckPoint_MGM
- - Cluster_A:
- - - FW01_A: Check Point 5400 R80.40
- - - FW02_A: Check Point 5400 R80.40
- - Cluster_B:
- - - FW03_B: Check Point 5400 R80.40
- - - FV04_B: Check Point 5400 R80.40

All four firewalls are managed through the Check Point SmartConsole R80.40

I looked everywhere but I can't find any setting related to log format. I suspect maybe it has to be done from command line but I don't even know if it's done through the SmartConsole or one by one on the single firewalls

**SOLUTION**: I created a Server object of the type "LogExporter/SIEM" instead of "Syslog" and configured the Management console (and not the cluster) to export logs to it. Right click on the management console object under "GATEWAYS & SERVERS" then Edit -> Logs -> Export

Comment: You almost always have much more configuration option through CLI than through a GUI. You should connect to the CLI on two devices from site A and B, and run "show configuration" then compare them

Comment: Please edit your question to include the [sanitized] device configurations. We cannot guess at how they are configured.

Comment: @RonMaupin Checkpoint firewalls don’t have a way to export the config into a text file or any other type of document.  They barely even have a CLI.  The best that can be done is typing out the security policy into a rough example of what it looks like in the GUI.

Comment: @JFL As I just said to Ron, there is effectively no CLI on Checkpoint firewalls. Everything is either done through the web interface if it’s for the device itself or through the Smart Console if it’s for the security policy or IDS/IPS etc.

Comment: @RonMaupin if I had access to the configuration of the devices that work properly I wouldn't be here asking

Comment: @mfloris SNMP is set on the individual devices, not via Smart Console, so you’ll need to open up a browser (preferably Internet Explorer, as I’ve never been too successful in getting it to work in Chrome or Firefox), and go to the management IP address of the individual units, such as `https://192.168.1.1`and then log in using the admin credentials. It may or may not be the same login as you use for Smart Console.

Comment: If you do not have access to the device configurations, your question is off topic here for not directly controlling the device. You seem to be asking us to speculate or guess at the configuration, but that is also off-topic here.

Comment: @RonMaupin Even if they have access, there is nothing *to* access since there is no way to export a config to sanitize and post here.  I told them already where SNMP is configured at, anyway.

Comment: It seems there's an LSMCli and an API but a quick search doesn't find any loging configuration. I would open a case on checkpoint support to have this sorted out.

Comment: @JesseP. I did set up SNMP individually but what does that have to do with syslog? I need to send traffic as in "Accept" and "Deny" TCP/IP events to an external syslog server. As of now I kind of do but the information contained in the log is incomplete and the lack of CSV makes it annoying to parse

Comment: @mfloris Sorry. I meant to type syslog, not SNMP.  That’s also set on the individual units, though.  There’s not really much control over what gets sent via syslog, and the lack of exporting almost anything is highly annoying. Checkpoint firewalls are as close to garbage as I’ve ever had the displeasure of working on before, and I’m so thankful that we either don’t have those customers anymore or they let me get rid of the Checkpoint units for something else.  Like JFL said, you should probably just open a case with their support to see what they can do to help (if anything).

Comment: As has been said, a detailed comparison of configs will be needed. Checkpoint has never made that easy. You'll need "expert CLI" access to see the text versions of their configs. I don't remember where they are, by they'll be *something*.C (objects.C and rules.C are the FW settings -- those are the only two I've ever needed to look at.)